# How to change Highcharts 3D Pie Chart Label and Tooltip Style?

Tags: css, charts, highcharts

I have a problem with the style of my Highcharts 3D pie chart -
it does not fit with dark theme.

How can I change the style of the title and the background of the tooltip?
[image: picture of the problematic styling]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add property style with property color for it.
This will help:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.style

```
  tooltip: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 1,
    shadow: true,
    useHTML: true,
    style: {
      padding: 0,
      color: 'grey'
    }
  },
```

Comment: Great, it worked.
Do you have any idea how I can change the white, unreadable text/font?

Comment: add fontFamily: 'fantasy' in style

Comment: Does not work, unfortunately, does not change anything.

Comment: can you show me your fragment code at https://codepen.io or https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: For example https://codepen.io/janisrozenfelds/pen/GdjNKg

Comment: Change your css. You have many property with "important".
For example, remove or change: text {fill: #fff !important;}. "When an important rule is used on a style declaration, this declaration overrides any other declarations. Although technically !important has nothing to do with specificity, it interacts directly with it". 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Then I would have had to adjust all the elements individually.
I have now tested a bit and with your tip then found the solution.
If this helps anyone, I just added this to the end of the css:

`.highcharts-text-outline{stroke: #000;}`

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to switch themes based on your website theme, you can use [`Highcharts.theme`](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/themes). Or you can set [title](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/title.style) color and [tooltip](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip) background color manually by using the following.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        style: {
            color: '#FF0000',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        backgroundColor: '#00000050'
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately this is not the solution.
I like to change the white not readable font, this code only changes the title of the chart.